Report Builder - Page Breaks
I have a report I've created in report builder. I will attach a screenshot.  On the left, I have a table with my columns etc.  To the right I created a couple of text boxes and expressions to the right of the table.  I want the preview to look just like I have here but when I preview it throws my textboxes that aren't aligned with the table to the last page. I found a fix was to create rows to the table and hide them but then when I export to excel I don't like that the hidden rows are still there. How can I make it so that when I run the report, all my textboxes and the second query are to the right?
How do I do this?
Tried everything and can't figure it out.

Put both tablixes in a rectangle. This allows them to be rendered next to each other.
